# Jquery terminal socket.io login

Tags: jquery, socket.io, jquery-terminal

I'm attempting to use jquery terminal with socket.io and I can't figure out how to get login to work correctly.

Can someone perhaps help me?

```
var terminal = $('#terminal').terminal(function(command, terminal) {
socket.emit('stdin', command);
},
{
login: function(username, password, callback) {
  var password =    CryptoJS.SHA1($('#login_password').val()).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  socket.emit('stdin', "/login "+ username + " " + password);
  // should wait for a response then callback
},
greetings: "You are authenticated",
tabcompletion: true,
exit: false,
completion: function(terminal, command, callback) {
    callback(['/login']);
},
onBlur: function() {
    // the height of the body is only 2 lines initialy
    return false;
},
onClear: function() {
    // the height of the body is only 2 lines initialy
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use different event then stdin for login:

```
login: function(username, password, callback) {
  var password = CryptoJS.SHA1($('#login_password').val()).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  socket.emit('login', "/login "+ username + " " + password);
  socket.on('auth', function(token) {
      callback(token);
  });
}
```

and then on the server you listen for login event and send auth event with token.